# how to put an onpressed in a part of a text - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I tried like this, but i need put a text like "to do something **click here**"

```
TextButton(
 onPressed: () {
   setState(() {
    isVisible = false;
});
},
  child: const Text('click here'),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`RichText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html).

```dart
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(children: [
  TextSpan(
    text: "to do something ",
  ),
  TextSpan(
      text: "click here",
      style: TextStyle(),
      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
        ..onTap = () {
          print("tapped");
        }),
])),
```

Make sure to `import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';`

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore the link for more